# Convert the below SQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How to convert the below SQL to postgreSQL

```
select sysdate, CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP),
       from_tz(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Australia/Darwin'),
       from_tz(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Australia/Darwin') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' 
from dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest is probably something like this:

```
select localtimestamp,
       localtimestamp at time zone 'Australia/Darwin',
       localtimestamp at time zone 'Australia/Darwin' at time zone 'America/New_York';
```

`localtimestamp` is essentially the same as both: `sysdate` **and** `cast(sysdate as timestamp)` in Oracle. Not sure what the intention is in the original query.

Comment: Thank you. Here in postgreSQL it changed the time component, but in oracle it doesn't change it (8/26/2020 7:17:17.000000 AM +09:30). is that possible in postgreSQL?

Comment: @Ram: no idea what you mean, it certainly returns three different time components: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=67760f3015dc498bd129cda855031a82 but without more details on what that query should achieve this is really hard to tell.

Comment: in oracle ,
CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP) = 26-AUG-20 **01.05.09.000000** PM  and
FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP),'AUSTRALIA/DARWIN') = 26-AUG-20 **01.05.09.000000** PM AUSTRALIA/DARWIN
,if you see there the time component remains same and appends the timezone . I needed same thing in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Are you in that time zone? Then just use `current_timestamp` in Postgres